# SQL Server stored procedure return code is NULL when called from TRY...CATCH block

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, try-catch, raiserror

Let's say I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC TestSP AS
select 'results selected' as column1
RAISERROR('this is an error',16,1)
--RETURN 3
```

If I call it like this,

```
DECLARE @ReturnCode int
EXEC @ReturnCode = TestSP
select @ReturnCode as ReturnCode
```

the return code will be -6.  If I `ALTER PROC` to uncomment the `--RETURN 3` line in the stored procedure, and again call it, the RETURN 3 will override and cause the return code to be 3.

If I call the procedure from within TRY...CATCH block,

```
DECLARE @ReturnCode int
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC @ReturnCode = TestSP
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'An error occurred.'
END CATCH
SELECT @ReturnCode as ReturnCode
```

the return code will be NULL.

Is using a return code (`EXEC @ReturnCode = TestSP`) not compatible with calling the stored procedure from within a TRY...CATCH block?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the return code is NULL when calling it from a TRY...CATCH block may have something to do with [batch abortion](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#returnvalue).

Microsoft SQL Server gives the programmer the option of EXECuting stored procedures in a way that captures the return code, as you said:

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = YourStoredProc
```

but you also have the option of calling your stored procedure from within a TRY...CATCH block, like this

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC YourStoredProc
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    <handle error>
END CATCH
```

It seems like there's no point in calling your stored procedure with `EXEC @ReturnCode = YourStoredProc` if you're going to call it from a TRY...CATCH block, because, as you indicated, the return code will be NULL. (Side note: If there is no TRY...CATCH or explicit 'RETURN *n*' in your code, RAISERROR will set the return code to -1 for an error severity of 11, -2 for 12, -3 for 13, etc. Note, however, that a severity of less than 20 will not stop execution of your code.)

The TRY..CATCH method gives you a lot more options and information to handle errors with.  Inside the CATCH block you can use the following system functions (taken from [TRY...CATCH documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)):

- ERROR_NUMBER() returns the number of the error.
- ERROR_SEVERITY() returns the severity.
- ERROR_STATE() returns the error state number.
- ERROR_PROCEDURE() returns the name of the stored procedure or trigger where the error occurred.
- ERROR_LINE() returns the line number inside the routine that caused the error.
- ERROR_MESSAGE() returns the complete text of the error message. The text includes the values supplied for any substitutable parameters, such as lengths, object names, or times.

You can test the output of these functions with the following code:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC TestSP  --A stored proc fashioned to cause an error
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
    'ERROR_NUMBER()', ERROR_NUMBER(),''
    UNION SELECT
    'ERROR_SEVERITY()',ERROR_SEVERITY(),''
    UNION SELECT
    'ERROR_STATE() ',ERROR_STATE(),''
    UNION SELECT
    'ERROR_PROCEDURE()',0,ERROR_PROCEDURE()
    UNION SELECT
    'ERROR_LINE()',ERROR_LINE(),''
    UNION SELECT
    'ERROR_MESSAGE()',0,ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

Finally, it should be noted that when using RAISERROR in a stored procedure called from a TRY...CATCH block, severities <= 10 are not even considered errors, and will not cause a CATCH block in the calling code to fire.  Severities 11+ will cause the CATCH block to fire.  In most cases, we should use severity level 16 with RAISERROR.

Comment: somewhat stating the obvious: that's what a TRY-CATCH block was designed to do!

Comment: It's information that was useful to me.  I thought it might be useful to someone else, so I documented it here on SO.